# How to upload file from a .NET MAUI application to the wwwroot?

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

How to upload a file from a local system file into wwwroot within .NET MAUI Blazor?

for example a video file, where I can add it into an HTML video player src.

Comment: There is no magical "upload" function that works with every webserver in the universe.  It would be a problem if every weberver allowed any random person to upload files without restriction.  You will need to create such a function, or determine what functions your existing webserver has to do this.

Comment: I'm using .NET MAUI Blazor, and I want to upload a specific file to the website I'm working on. To the wwwroot folder specifically.